# Flask-Login module 'app' has no attribute 'after_request'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to use Flask-Login with Flask, but when I try to initialize the `LoginManager` class with the app ([as shown in the documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuring-your-application)) I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'after_request'
```

Here's (a snippet of) my code:

```py
from flask_login import LoginManager
login_manager = LoginManager()

...

def create_app():
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    login_manager.init_app(app)
```

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but with a Dash app.

> Code:

```
app = Dash(__name__,...)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

> Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Dash' object has no attribute 'after_request'
```

### Solution

Instead of using the *app* object directly, it worked to initiate the login manager with the server porperty:

```
app = Dash(__name__,...)
server = app.server
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(server)
```

> Solution taken from https://github.com/RafaelMiquelino/dash-flask-login

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out what was causing the problem. Before the `init_app` line I imported my models (for Flask-Migrate) like this:

```
import app.models.<model-name-here>
```

I changed it to

```
from app.models.<model-name-here> import <model-name-here>
```

I still don't know why that caused issues but it works now.